# B2C Hide the Social Intro

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I updated our version of self asserted to 2.1.2 to address the new password reset flow. Doing this has added the social_intro to our custom log in page.

I have added the local_intro_generic to the page and it works fine, However the social_intro still show up. We are not allowing for any social login and I don't want it displayed. I can edit it... but I don't see a way to hide it either in the documents or any other search.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the html file that is getting referenced for that page. Hide the divs that you don't need after checking the class names of the divs using inspect element.